# Loop over the Mongodb objects to get the values in Meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

I am first Time working With Meteorjs and MongoDB. I am working on a Q&A application. where I have a list of objects which i got using Meteor database call. I want to looper over the list and want to split one of its attribute to the length 50 and then want to send a list of these splitted objects to the database.what I have is this

```
Template.questions.questions = function () {
questions= Meteor.questions.find({topic_id: Session.get("currentTopicId")});
return questions
}
```

Every question object in the questions list has an attribute question_text. Using loop i want to split this attribute to length of fifty and then want to push that to an empty list and return that list . Like

```
questions_list=[]
for(i=0;i<questions.length;i++){
    question=questions[i].question_text[0:50]   // python syntex to get first 50 char of a string
    questions_list.push(question
}
return questions_list
```

and My HTML is like

```
<tbody>
            {{#each questions}}
            <tr>
                <td class="span2" style="overflow:hidden;width:50px">
                    <a href="#" data-id="{{_id}}" class="edit"> {{question_text}}</a>
                </td>

            </tr>

            {{/each}}

            </tbody>
```

suggest me guys how can i acieve this in meteorjs. my problem is when i try to loop over this questions list there are many attributes like Collection, Results, Queries. here i am unable to iterate this list of objects.

In the same way how can i get the error message thrown back by meteorjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you list of shortened texts of all questions matching a query:

```
var questions = Questions.find({...}).map(function(question) {
    return question.text.substr(0,50);
});
```

You could use it directly in a helper:

```
Template.questions.questions = function () {
    return Questions.find({...}).map(function(question) {
        return question.text.substr(0,50);
    });
};
```

---

By the way, `Questions.find({...})` does not return a **list** of questions, but a cursor object that you can use to manipulate query data in an effective way (like that `map` method above). To get raw array, you need to use `fetch` on that cursor: `Questions.find({...}).fetch()`.

Comment: Okay, that was the problem. before today i used only django where request returns array. and same i was trying here. Thanx a lot. I did console.log(question.question_text.substr(0,50)) it is working. But nothing is returned to the template. Thank you Hubert OG

Comment: I think mistake is in my template. see the template is it right?

Comment: If you are using the `Template.questions.questions` as supplied by Hubert above then that is returning a list of strings. I notice in your template you're expecting each element in the array to have an `{{_id}}` and a `{{questionText}}` property. To do that try:

`Template.questions.questions = function() {
  return Questions.find({...}).map(function(question) {
    return {_id: question._id, questionText: question.text.substr(0,50)};
  });
}`

Comment: Indeed. What you return in the map callback is what is given to the template. If you return a string, you can only display it by calling `{{this}}`. If you want to use multiple values, return an object as Bruce written.

Comment: Thank you Bruce, Thank you HUbert OG, Yes, I am returning multiple values as a key value pair dictionary , but in template still I am unable to render these. I am checking on console.log. Complete objects are there. but not rendering on template.

Comment: HUbart OG, it is working fine. Perhaps i was doing some mistake there. thats why it was not rendering  there. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If you're just displaying the data you could create a handlebars helper:

```
Template.questions.helpers({
  first50: function(question) {
    return question.text.substr(0,50);
  }
});
```

Then add the helper:

```
Template.questions.questions = function() {
  return Questions.find({...});
};
```

Then in your template you could do:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each questions}}
    <tr>
      <td class="span2" style="overflow:hidden;width:50px">
        <a href="#" data-id="{{_id}}" class="edit"> {{first50 question_text}}</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you Bruce Hubbard.If I am trying the solution you given it gives me recompute questions exception.